# Gurobi options in GAMS

Tags: gurobi, gams-math

I've recently moved to Gurobi and we use GAMS.

Have been struggling to implement Gurobi options, is there a way to use Gurobi options directly? With a file or something like that.

For instance, I want to use the following options and have not found a GAMS correspondence:

Scaleflag;

MIPFocus;

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What do you mean with "GAMS correspondence"? Both options you mentioned are available as GAMS/Gurobi options (see https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/S_GUROBI.html#GUROBI_SUMMARY_OF_OPTIONS). If you need more info, how to set solver options in GAMS, check this: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_SolverUsage.html#BASIC_USAGE_SOLVER_OPTION_FILE

Comment: @Lutz if I write option MIPFocus = 3; then an error occurs:  Error 250 in x.gms,7,16][LST:12]
    Unknown option.  valid are -

Comment: You wrote it to the gms file? That does not work, since it is a solver link option and need to be written to the solver option file. Please check the second link I posted in my first comment.